# The iap.subscribe(Skus[]) mechanism is returning false even when my user is subscribed already (sandbox)

Tags: java, ios, mobile, codenameone

I used the demo app for auto renewing subscriptions to implement autorenewing subscriptions on my app. I am able to log in and subscribe which will bring up the standard ios subscription dialogs. However the next time i Log in i call the iap.isSubscribed() mechanism from Codenameone , the result is always false (Is this because i am in the testflight environment?). When the isSubscribed method returns fault i send the user to the subscribe page which has a button to subscribe, when this button is pressed i get a dialog informing me i am already subscribed.

I have attempted to use the emulator as well as an actual apple iphone6+ neither of which got back the successfully subscribed receipt for the user

```
@Override
public void initForm() {
    theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");
    //create a new content container
    Container content = new Container();
    iap = Purchase.getInAppPurchase();
    // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
    // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    // Define a receipt loader
    iap.setReceiptStore(createReceiptStore());
    /*
    The form needs to be split up into 3 parts 1 part for Successful subscriptions 
    1 part for paymens that have not been sucecssful yet 
    and  1 part for people who have not subscribed yet
     */
    if (!iap.isSubscribed(Skus)) {
        EMCDialogFactory.showMessageDialog("Subscription Failed", "Is Subscribed upon login: " + iap.isSubscribed(SKU_1_MONTH));
        content = createNonSubscribedHomeScreen();
    } else {
        EMCDialogFactory.showMessageDialog("Subscription Failed", "Is Subscribed upon login: " + iap.isSubscribed(SKU_1_MONTH));
        content = createSuccessfulHomeScreen();
    }

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(BorderLayout.CENTER, content);

}


/**
 * Creates a receipt loader to load receipts from our web service
 *
 * @return
 */
private ReceiptStore createReceiptStore() {
    //fetch all your receipts from the server to be used by the receipt store 
    listOfReceipts = fetchReceipts();
    return new ReceiptStore() {
        @Override
        public void fetchReceipts(SuccessCallback<Receipt[]> callback) {
            List<Receipt> out = new ArrayList<>();
            //loop through the receipts
            for (Receipt res : listOfReceipts) {
                //create a new receipt
                Receipt r = new Receipt();
                r.setTransactionId(res.getTransactionId());
                r.setPurchaseDate(res.getPurchaseDate());
                r.setQuantity(1);
                r.setSku(res.getSku());
                //check cancellation and expiry
                if (res.getCancellationDate() != null) {
                    r.setCancellationDate(res.getCancellationDate());
                }
                if (res.getExpiryDate() != null) {
                    r.setExpiryDate(res.getExpiryDate());
                }
                out.add(r);
            }
            callback.onSucess(out.toArray(new Receipt[out.size()]));
        }

        @Override
        public void submitReceipt(Receipt r, SuccessCallback<Boolean> callback) {
            submitTheReceipt(r, callback);
        }

    };
}
```

There is no Error message that shows up it simply returns false that i am not subscribed and it goes back to my subscription page. However if i press my subscribe button again it says that i am already subscribed.

Comment: Can you check if a receipt is returned from the fetch receipts?
I would suggest checking the subscription after the receipts are initialized and not during loading code as it might trigger IO.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I have checked and the receipts are returned

Comment: Try using `wasPurchased`. Some of the subscription primitives underwent major changes and it's possible that `isSubscribed` broke along the way